# Get rid of launch javafx

Tags: java, window, javafx-8, game-engine, program-entry-point

I am writing a little render/game "engine" where you have the possibility to, as it says, easily create a game or render something. For this I want a Window - Class which can be instantiated. Since I am using JavaFX there is a problem I really do not know how to solve. As far as I know I need the Main containing the launch to be in the class where I do the "extends Application" stuff. Now I want to know if there is a way to create a Window - Class, which can be instantiated and so easily used like in the Main - Method (like in AWT or Swing). This would also give the possibility to create multiple windows.
Like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Window window = new Window();
}
```

This would presuppose that there is no more launch(args).
Thank you in advance. :D

Comment: The `launch(args)` method is what start javaFX. If you don't run this method, using any kind of javaFX classes will throw RunTimeExceptions. If you want multiple views for a game, look at using Stages, Scenes, and Panes.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking, but it sounds to me like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please try to better explain what you are trying to achieve (regardless of how you think you may achieve this).

Comment: Just think of the `start()` method in the `Application` subclass as replacing the `main` method in a traditional Java application. Just move whatever you want to do in `main` to `start`.

Comment: The problem I had was that I wanted to have a class where you do not need to inherit from Application to get a window. As Brydenr said the launch(args) start JavaFX so I created a static Method in the Window - Class which iherits from Application, which calls the _launch_ - Method. Now I guess I can not do it the way I described, but I can do it all static like in lwjgl2 in the Display - Class. Thanks for your help :)